# PHP caching gone wrong? Element used as reference, I can't see why

Tags: php, xampp

Something wicked has happened. I've lost two hours boiling a problem down to this - two arrays of objects behaved as if one was a reference to the other.

```
foreach ($this->screenElements as $element) {
    echo($this->screenElementsSearch['tasksSeverity']->getValue());
    echo "-";

    $element->setValue('1cosmetical');

    echo($this->screenElementsSearch['tasksSeverity']->getValue());
    echo "\n";
}
```

PrintOut:

```
 - 1cosmetical
1cosmetical - 1cosmetical
1cosmetical - 1cosmetical
```

I neither set up $screenElementsSearch as a reference of $screenElements nor $element as a reference of $screenElements in the `for` loop.

Then, all of a sudden (I called `phpinfo()` to look up the PHP version to post this, 5.2.9 on Win7/Xampp lite by the way), it stopped happening. I know how this sounds. But printout changed to:

```
 - 
 - 
 -
```

like it ought to. Now, my question to you is: Has PHP or XAMPP some caching going on that *may* have caused this behaviour? Just in case it happens again, because then I'll bang my head against a wall.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: How do you obtain `screenElements` and `screenElementsSearch`?

Comment: Just as a reminder: in a foreach you are working with (in this case $element) copies. Have no clue how the search and the elements are connected, so can't help you there

Comment: @BoltClock $this->screenElementsSearch = readEntityFields(); $this->screenElements = array_merge(someMethod(), $this->screenElementsSearch);    I don't use any &reference, nowhere. I've checked.

Comment: Do you get the first output by running under PHP 4?

Comment: @Nanne That's exactly the problem! screenElementsSearch is not connected to $element at all - I'm looping through an entirely different array of objects.

Comment: @BoltClock - I haven't got any PHP4 installation to resort to, never had... And now the problem is gone, anyway. I was guessing that ... perhaps ... PHP stores the variable references somewhere and then something prevented it from renewing them.

Comment: @PeerBr: Strange, but as far as I can see, based on your comment the first case should be what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment:

```
$this->screenElementsSearch = readEntityFields();
$this->screenElements = array_merge(someMethod(), $this->screenElementsSearch);
```

You are creating `screenElements` based on the contents of `screenElementsSearch`. In PHP 5, this actually copies *references* to the element objects from one array to the other. So both arrays hold their own references to the *same objects*, without you having to use `&`.

If the output is blank after you called `phpinfo()`, you probably triggered a switch somewhere that changed PHP versions on your server... that function by itself shouldn't really change anything though.

Comment: Is there a way to produce an array holding copies, not references? Because the application really needs them to be hold different values.

Comment: @PeerBr: Not trivially, but PHP lets you perform object shallow copies using the [`clone` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php).

Comment: To the afterworld: Shocking, but true.
class car {
    public $ID = 2;
}
$oldCars = array(new car);
$cars = array_merge($oldCars, array(new car));
$oldCars[0]->ID = 5;
echo $cars[0]->ID, $cars[1]->ID; //result = 52

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll create screenElements with the same method that created screenElementsSearch instead. This might even make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

They don't need to be references. In PHP (like most other languages) objects have reference semantics. That is to say that assigning an object to two different variables will not clone the object. This is unlike scalar values and arrays.

In old versions of php (php 4), objects actually *had* value semantics. That is why php 4 code had ampersands all over the place.

Comment: "This is unlike scalar values and arrays" -> so adding an object to two different arrays will create references to it, not copies?